# Access static method from class in same package via. main()

Tags: java

I've never tried to do this before and am a little flummoxed.  Two classes in the same package:

```
package test;

public class One {
    public static String test () { return "hello world"; }
}
```

and:

```
package test;

public class Two {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(One.test());
    }
}
```

If I try and `javac Two.java` *inside* the test/ directory, I get "cannot find symbol" for One.  However, if I do it from the parent directory, `javac test/Two`, it compiles, and can then be run `java test/Two` -- but again not from inside (throws a **NoClassDefFoundError**  saying the proper name of the class is `test/Two`, not `Test`).

Not a big deal, but curious if there is a better way around it, and if anyone can help me understand the issue.  I actually do not need "Two" to be a formal member of the test package, I just need to have it in the same directory and compilable there.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk: The "confusing the compiler" is just a matter of how it's invoked, and has nothing to do with the code itself. While I'm not a huge fan of static methods for various reasons, I think your comment is over the top.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk :  I absolutely agree, and don't worry, I won't -- which begs the question of *why* I want to do this, but the answer is a bit long-winded and dreary ;)

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk: So do you never have any class ever aware of *any* other class? Never use *any* static methods? There's a time and a place for everything. You "cannot ever see a need" for a public static method? I'd be intrigued to see a significantly-sized code-base that you've worked on, which *never* has any tight coupling. (Also note that the coupling is only in one direction: `Two` depends on `One`, but not vice versa. So it's not as bad as it could be, by a long chalk.)

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk: Okay, that makes a lot more sense then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *compile* from the parent directory with:

```
javac test/Two.java test/One.java
```

(You might also want to use `-d` to say where you want the class files to end up. Note that you *could* just compile `test/One.java` and let the compiler find the class it depends on, but I find it cleaner to just specify all the source code you want to compile.)

And *run* with the package-qualified class name:

```
java test.Two
```